# Get socket.io.js from NodeJS

Tags: socket.io

I try to use `Socket.io` with my website.
My app.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end(content);
    });
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Connected !');
});


server.listen(8080);
```

My index.html (with Nginx):

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
 </script>
```

When I'm connect to my website, i have that error in my client console (chrome):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

What is the problem ?
Thanks !

Comment: If that's your entire index.html, then you need to put it into an actual HTML page wrapper:  `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script src=...></script></head></html>`.  It appears your browser is objecting to the index.html you are sending it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your HTML file being served to the references a file local to your server, specifically

> /socket.io/socket.io.js

. Your app.js file should either include the contents of that file if you want to serve it directly from the file system, or better yet reference a CDN for the client to get the socket.io script file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script> var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080'); </script>
```

Comment: socket.io automatically supports the `/socket.io/socket.io.js` route by itself.  So, this is not likely the issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 Cool didn't know that, but I tried this locally and the error went away